# How to Access Terminal Over Serial Port in Raspberry pi 4

Tags: uart, serial, linux, terminal

I'm trying to Read and Write over Serial Port to Terminal in Headless Linux That I Installed on my Rpi4.
is That even Possible? is so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have/want any other means of access to your RPi besides the serial port you could follow Jeff Geerling guide available here: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2021/attaching-raspberry-pis-serial-console-uart-debugging

Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).